# How to attach middleware to an existing named route from a package in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

I'm trying to extend an existing application without modifying its source code.
The application has a named route called `wizard-add`.
Is there a way to register `\MyPackage\MyMiddleware` with the existing route?
I tried attaching it via `Route::getRoutes()->getByName('wizard-add')->middleware(\MyPackage\MyMiddleware::class);` but since packages are registered before the routes are read, `Route::getRoutes()` returns an empty collection.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Since I didn't find a way to solve this, I extended the app's controllers and put my logic inside.

```
namespace MyPackage\Controllers;
use App\Controllers\WizardController;

class MyPackageWizardController extends WizardController { ... }
```

and then in my service provider's `register()` method:

```
$this->app->bind(WizardController::class, MyPackageWizardController::class);
```

So everytime the app attempts to instantiate `WizardController`, it instantiates `MyPackageWizardController` instead. I don't know if there are any drawbacks but so far this has been working perfectly for me.